# Opening new pages with

Tags: javascript

I've tried what seems like dozens of different solutions to this all with different failures.  Basically I've built an array that has a bunch of IDs in it and I and using javascript to loop through them and open pages that go through an archiving process.  These need to be delayed because it takes about a minute for each one to occur.  Here's what I have currently:

```
    var i = 0
    function openPage() {
        while (i < Array.length) {
            window.setTimeout(go(i), 60000*i;);
            i++;

        }
    }


    function go(i) {
        window.open('http://localhost:12575/DD7RO2.aspx?id=' + Array[i][0]);
    }
```

Then I call openPage from a button press.

For some reason this throws an error of "Invalid argument" at the window.setTimeout line.  I can't seem to figure out why that is.  Every other iteration of this that I've tried has either opened a single window (the first in the array) and stopped, or opened everything completely disregarding the timeout.  I feel like this one might actually work since it's actually doing something different.  Any help would be be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are evaluating `go(i)` when it's passed as an argument. That function executes in the loop. Instead, you should return a function object, and that will be executed when the timer fires.

Do not do `function(){go(i);}`, that's a classic closure error. You would end up calling the function`go(i)` each time the event fired, but with the same, final, value of `i`. The scope of `i` is the enclosing function, so by the time the timeouts run it will have a value of `Array.length - 1`.

Instead something like

```
window.setTimeout((function (j){return function(j){go(j)}})(i), 60000*i;);
```

To spell that out;

```
(
  function (j) {
    var k = j;
    return function() {
      go(k)
     }
   }
 )(i);
```

This looks confusing, but that's the way JS works.

1. It immediately executes a function with the value of `i`.
2. That returns a function object, but that function is in a closure in which the value of `i` bound at that point in time.
3. The function object is executed when the timeout event fires, with the value of `i` bound correctly.

Comment: That is indeed confusing.  I'm going to have to look at this for a minute because it's currently not working for me.  It also says that the second semicolon is unnecessary but upon removing it, I get a different error.

Comment: Have a play with it in the console to familiarise yourself with it, and read a JS book.

Comment: I got it functioning but it seems like it always returns undefined.  Am I missing something here?  http://jsfiddle.net/Rp2km/1/

Comment: Ah yes! You found a problem in my code. Variable arguments aren't included in the closure, annoyingly, so you have to explicitly declare them. I've added `var k = j`, which explicitly 'takes a copy' in the local scope. I also changed the variable names to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how it works now.  I think I just needed to wrap my head around the way javascript executes.  This essentially forces it to complete the function before it completes the loop so it doesn't just fly to the end.

Comment: Also, for anyone using asp.net like I am with this, make sure you set a put a return false; after you call the function so it doesn't do a postback and ruin everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ go(i); }, 60000*i;);
```

Here you go!

Comment: This is an improvement, but it won't work because of the classic "setting up an event handler in a loop" problem.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but figured it gets the OP a little closer

Comment: Giving someone an answer with one of the beginner JavaScript errors in it is even worse!

Comment: I had this before but it didn't give any response so I moved on.