# SetTimeout within a while loop in JS

Tags: javascript

Having a massive mind blank, can someone explain why `setTimeout` is not working inside this while loop:

http://jsbin.com/aHAcIsE/1/edit

```
var checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'),
    i = checks.length,
    arr = [1, 4, 7];

function check(index){
  checks[index].checked = true;
}

while(i--){
  if(arr.indexOf(i) > -1){
    setTimeout(function(){
      check(i);
    }, 1000);        
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the heck would you want to set a timeout inside a loop?

Comment: typical callback and loop problem - `i` is already zero by the time the timeouts have elapsed.

Comment: Try using an interval here instead.

Comment: I think you should use 'setInterval'

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? The variable `i` seems to be intended as an index in the array, but then you use `indexOf` to look for the value of `i` in the array, which means that only the first item in the array will be used.

Comment: @Tyagi the OP apparently wants a constrained number of callbacks to be fired - why on earth do you think `setInterval` would help?!

Comment: You know that incorrect answer you gave to this question? Same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546726/opening-new-pages-with/19546804

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that when the callback of the `setTimeout()` is finally executed, all calls of that callback refer to the same variable `i`, which has the same value for all instances.

Straight forward solution (submit `i` as a parameter to the callback; then each callback receives its own copy of `i`).
(The additional passing of parameters is not supported by IE<9 according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout), so we need a slightly modified version for those browsers.)

```
// IE9+ version
while(i--){
  if(arr.indexOf(i) > -1){
    setTimeout(function( index ){
      check(index);
    }, 1000, i );        
  }
}

// for IE below version 9
while(i--){
  if(arr.indexOf(i) > -1){
    !function( index ) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        check(index);
      }, 1000 ); 
    }( i );       
  }
}
```

Restructuring solution (here no callbacks inside a loop are needed and hence the problem does not exist):

```
setTimeout( function(){   
  while(i--){
    if(arr.indexOf(i) > -1){
      check(index);
    }   
  } 
}, 1000 );
```

Comment: passing parameters to the `setTimeout` callback is not standard

Comment: you're on a losing battle here - if you didn't already, please just close vote the question.

Comment: @Alnitak Noted and corrected. And I already voted to close ,-)